# Spatial Hibernate 5 On Wildfly 10

Tags: hibernate, wildfly, postgis, spatial, hibernate-spatial

I am using Wildfly 10 and developing an application using Spatial Hibernate 5 with PostGIS database. I am getting the below error in runtime.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Received object of type org.postgresql.util.PGobject
```

Can anyone suggest some good tutorials as on how to use Spatial Hibernate with Wildfly 10?

Comment: Same here. Where you able to solve this yet?

Comment: Did you find a way around this, I really dont want to do that way around @Toastor suggested

Comment: Check this answer to find the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46222613/1126380, basically you need to deploy all the required libs in your wildfly before running your application.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and I just fixed it.  It is basically a dependency issue.  The problem is that you are loading the postgresql and/or postgis jars on your wildfly modules and on you deployments WEB-INF/lib.
I connect to my database with a regular DS on my standalone.xml

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/mygisDS" pool-name="mygisDS" use-java-context="true">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/keycloak</connection-url>
                    <driver>org.postgresql</driver>
                    <transaction-isolation>TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED</transaction-isolation>
                    <pool>
                        <min-pool-size>10</min-pool-size>
                        <max-pool-size>100</max-pool-size>
                        <prefill>true</prefill>
                        <use-strict-min>false</use-strict-min>
                        <flush-strategy>FailingConnectionOnly</flush-strategy>
                    </pool>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>user</user-name>
                        <password>XXXXXX</password>
                    </security>
                </datasource>
```

My drivers

```
<driver name="org.postgresql" module="org.postgresql">
                        <xa-datasource-class>org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                    </driver>
```

I tried as @Toastor said, it might have solve his issues but it didnt work with me. Although he gave me a few clues.

So most documentation around the internet is outdated, and there is not much on hibernate spatial 5.  I added postgis-jdbc to my maven to my postgresql's module.xml inside my wildfly, but as I was reading THIS IS NOT NECESSARY in Hibernate Spatial 5.X.  Wildfly 10 uses 5.0.7 by default, I was using hibernate 5.1.0.Final, so I did not set the scope of any hibernate component on my pom.xml as "provided".
But everything kept failing too. So I traced my libraries.

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

You have to check for any postgresql libraries that are called or any postgis libraries. What I found out is that Hibernate Spatial 5.1 has some postgresql dependencies, so I excluded them from hibernate spatial.

```
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        </exclusion>
```

I did this and I found a problem with PGobject, it said something like class not found.  So I added it to jboss-deployment-structure.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="org.postgresql" />
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

And this did the work. If you have a similar problem use maven dependency:tree to trace your libraries.

Answer (score 2):

After struggling for days, I found this solution:

Don't connect to your database through a datasource defined on your wildfly. Instead, in your persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="org.hibernate.events.jpa" transaction-type="JTA">
   <properties>
       <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisDialect"/>
       <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
       <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/yourdatabase"/>
       <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="username"/>
       <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="password"/>
       <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size" value="5"/>

       <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
       <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>

       <property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth" value="5"/>

       <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
   </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Because the early 5.0.x versions of hibernate apparently had no proper integration of hibernate-spatial and to avoid classpath problems, I added the file jboss-deployment-structure.xml to my META-INF:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
         <exclusions>
            <module name="org.hibernate" />
            <module name="org.postgresql" />
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

This will prevent the wildfly provided hibernate to be used by your deployment so that you can instead add a dependency for the most recent hibernate version (5.1.0 as of this writing). You will then need to add dependencies for hibernate, hibernate-spatial and postgresql-jdbc.

Also note that hibernate 5 doesn't require the @Type annotation anymore.

I have managed to get my project working with the settings above and one of my entities featuring the following attribute / column:

```
@Column(columnDefinition = "geometry(Point,4326)")
private Point position;
```

I hope it helps, good luck!

**Edit:**
Using this approach, you need to add your postgresql jdbc driver as a dependency to your project.

**Edit:**

I have prepared a working sample project demonstrating the use of wf10/hibernate5/postgis - check it out on github:

https://github.com/Pulvertoastmann/wf10postgis/

Comment: And using jta-data-source?

Comment: No, no data-source required. But here's a fun bit: If you _do_ create a data-source, the above example would work without providing database credentials in your persistence.xml. The credentials of the wf ds will be used. I don't know why... some odd things are going on apparently. To be honest, I stopped investigating once it worked and turned to other things, so I can't offer you any further explanation...

Comment: @Toastor, I just tried your sample project. I can insert geometry values, but can't get them back. I created an issue in your sample project github. Hope you can help me. Here is my original post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46164275/received-object-of-type-org-postgresql-util-pgobject#comment79370882_46164275